# Alternative FTP client libraries for Erlang

Tags: ftp, erlang

There are at least two HTTP client libraries for Erlang in addition to [`httpc`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) in the OTP library (which seems to be generally regarded as buggy and clunky): [`ibrowse`](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse) and [`lhttpc`](https://github.com/oscarh/lhttpc). Are there similar alternatives to [`ftp`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ftp.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but hopefully others will find this useful:

[lftpc](https://github.com/potatosalad/lftpc) is a "Lightweight Erlang FTP Client" modeled after [lhttpc](https://github.com/esl/lhttpc) and [dlhttpc](https://github.com/ferd/dlhttpc) which we have been using in production for the last 6 months or so.

It's not very well documented right now, but here is an example using [`test.rebex.net`](http://test.rebex.net/):

```
1> lftpc:start().
ok
2> {ok, {_, _, Socket}} = lftpc:connect("test.rebex.net", 21, []).
{ok,{undefined,{220,[<<"FTP on test.rebex.net ready...">>]},
               <0.65.0>}}
3> lftpc:login(Socket, [{username, <<"demo">>}, {password, <<"password">>}], infinity, []).
{ok,[{undefined,{331,[<<"Password required for demo.">>]},
                undefined},
     {undefined,{230,[<<"User demo logged in.">>]},undefined}]}
4> lftpc:cd(Socket, <<"pub">>, infinity, []).
{ok,{undefined,{250,
                [<<"CWD command successful. \"/pub\" is current directory.">>]},
               undefined}}
```

By default, there are no decoders used for the control or data connections.  So when we list a directory containing 2 files: `example` and `test` we get back:

```
5> lftpc:nlist(Socket, infinity, []).
{ok,{{150,
      [<<"Data connection accepted from 173.198.175.141:53504; transfer starting.">>]},
     {226,[<<"Transfer ok.">>]},
     [<<"example\r\ntest\r\n">>]}}
```

We can specify a `data_decoder`:

```
6> lftpc:nlist(Socket, infinity, [{partial_download, []}, {data_decoder, lftpc_format:nlst_decoder()}]).
{ok,{{150,
      [<<"Data connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54359; transfer starting.">>]},
     {226,[<<"Transfer ok.">>]},
     [[<<"example">>,<<"test">>]]}}
```

We can also specify `partial_download` to receive the data in chunks:

```
7> {ok, {_, Download}} = lftpc:nlist(Socket, infinity, [{partial_download, []}, {data_decoder, lftpc_format:nlst_decoder()}]).
{ok,{{150,
      [<<"Data connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54403; transfer starting.">>]},
     <0.86.0>}}
8> receive {data_part, Download, Data} -> Data end.
[<<"example">>,<<"test">>]
9> receive {ftp_eod, Download, Message} -> Message end.
{226,[<<"Transfer ok.">>]}
```

Take a look at the main [`src/lftpc.erl`](https://github.com/potatosalad/lftpc/blob/1.0.1/src/lftpc.erl) file, there are [high-level](https://github.com/potatosalad/lftpc/blob/1.0.1/src/lftpc.erl#L32-L60) and [low-level](https://github.com/potatosalad/lftpc/blob/1.0.1/src/lftpc.erl#L62-L114) functions depending on your needs.  You can always drop down to `lftpc:request/3,4,5,6` and `lftpc:start_transfer/3` to do anything custom.

Answer (score 2):

You may or may not find this useful but I can explain what we did for our project. We specifically needed to use `sftp` in Erlang, and found it buggy and incompatible with some server configurations. We ended up writing a simple ftp/sftp client in Java using **jsch**, and using `JInterface` to connect it to Erlang. We wasted a couple days trying to fight with Erlang's ftp implementation and make it work, but ultimately ended up developing and testing an implementation in Java with JInterface in just a few hours. Good luck.

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add a dependency on Java for this project. Would have tried it otherwise.